# Error: "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Tags: unix, ansible, devops

When I am trying to test on this server I am getting this error:

> "module_stderr": "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo",
>   "module_stdout": "",
>   "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
>   "rc": 1

How can I know what would be the reason, and how to solve it?

Comment: Please add your playbook and the output to your question.  Do you have pipelining enabled?

Answer (score 0):

In visudo

Add a line
Defaults:myuser        !requiretty

Where myuser is the ssh account of ansible